# how set the value in Model inside Spring MVC annotation Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cassandra

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/excelDataView", method=RequestMethod.GET )
    public ModelAndView getExcel(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response){
    log.info("Inside getExcel()");
        List<DataValidationResults> dataValidationResults = new ArrayList<DataValidationResults>();
        dataValidationResults = dataValidationDelegate.exportData(TaskId);
        log.info("dataValidationDelegate.exportData(TaskId) value " + dataValidationDelegate.exportData(TaskId));
        request.setAttribute("dataValidationResults", dataValidationResults);
        return new ModelAndView(new ExcelDataView(), "dataValidationResultsModel", dataValidationResults);
    }
```

Comment: public class ExcelDataView extends AbstractExportXlsView{  @Override
 public void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { equest.getAttribute()
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     
          List<DataValidationResults> dataValidationResults = (List<DataValidationResults>) model.get("dataValidationResults");

Comment: why are you writing other part of question in comment section.
Edit your question.

Comment: Getting Null value at this place          List<DataValidationResults> dataValidationResults = (List<DataValidationResults>) model.get("dataValidationResults");